# Use list key value in when in Ansible

Tags: ansible

How can I use the list key value in `when` without using jinja2 templating?

Below is a example that does not work:

```
- name: "Give sudo rights"
  user: 
    group: "{{users[item].username}}"
    groups: sudo
    append: yes
    name: "{{ users[item].username }}"
  become: true
  when: {{ users[item].sudorights }} == yes
  with_items: "{{addusers}}"
```

List:

```
users:
  john:
    username: john
    sudorights: yes
```

Comment: You should consider banning "It's not working" from your vocabulary on Q&A sites like SO, at least when used on its own. [It does not accurately describe your problem](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the [documentation on conditionnals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#basic-conditionals-with-when)

> The when clause is a raw Jinja2 expression without double curly braces

Moreover, comparing to literal true/false is one of [ansible-lint bad practice rule check](https://ansible-lint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/default_rules.html#don-t-compare-to-literal-true-false)

Taking the above into account, you can fix your expression as:

```yaml
when: users[item].sudorights | bool
```

**One step further**

You may have in your `users` list some users without `sudorights` defined at all. In such a case, the above condition will fire an error and stop ansible processing as soon as such an `item` is encountered. To make sure this does not happen, you can default the value of this parameter if it is not present:

```yaml
when: users[item].sudorights | default(false) | bool
```

Comment: I tried without curly braces and then the main problem was the `== true`. Thank you very much. I will also use your second tip.